# Using regular expressions to find and replace within a string with additional style

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some raw text I need to output, I also have a search box to highlight parts of the text that match what is entered in the search box.

This works, where find is the search box contents:

```
replace="<span class='highlight'>"+find+"</span>";
var results = drawstring.replace(new RegExp(find, 'gi'), replace);
return results;
```

My problem is that i want a match regardless of case but I'll be replacing with the exact input of the user. I want to retain the case of the original value before the replace, how can this be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the matched string inside the replace value:

```
replace="<span class='highlight'>$&</span>";
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter